# Linq Groupby How to Sum Different 4 Model Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I've three model properties like:

```
public decimal Date{ get; set; }
public decimal Money{ get; set; }
public string CityId{ get; set; } // grouping property
```

I need to group by "CityId" than i want to select date and money grouped by "CityId".

Code for this:

```
var results = model.Select(x => new MyViewModel(){ 
                                    Date= x.Date,
                                    Money= x.Money,
                                    CityId= x.CityId,
                 }).GroupBy(x=>x.CityId)
                   .ToList();
```

I can get what i want with this Linq query. Than i want to match up my values with this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
 {
     NewList myList = new NewList();
     myList.Date= results[i].   // i cant get my properties(Date,Money, CityId)
     myList.Money= results[i].  // i cant get my properties(Date,Money, CityId)
     myList.CityId= results[i].  // i cant get my properties(Date,Money, CityId)
 }
```

After spelling hours, what's the wrong with this code? How can i get `Date`, `Money`, `CityId` properties?

Comment: `results[i]` is a collection that has `Key` property. I guess you don't need the `GroupBy` ..

Comment: could you please gives us an input and a desired output?

Comment: You might actually want `OrderBy` instead of `GroupBy` since you don't seem to be aggregating anything.

Comment: You also might want use `results.Count` in your `for` condition, since you're iterating over `results`, not `model`.

Comment: what do you mean by match up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupBy` returns groupings of items, an object than contains all grouped items and a key which this group belongs to. So currently your `results` is of type that looks something like `List<int, IGrouping<MyViewModel>>`. What you are looking for is apparently `List<MyViewModel>`, for which you can use `SelectMany`:

```
var results = model.Select(x => new MyViewModel()
{ 
     Date= x.Date,
     Money= x.Money,
     CityId= x.CityId,
})
.GroupBy(x=>x.CityId)
.SelectMany(x => x)
.ToList();
```

This should flatten your groupings into a single list, with items ordered in groups.

**Update.** Note that the code above assumes that you are using `GroupBy` intentionally. As pointed out in comments, if this is the only use case you have, then simple `OrderBy` might be a better alternative:

```
var results = model.Select(x => new MyViewModel()
{ 
     Date= x.Date,
     Money= x.Money,
     CityId= x.CityId,
})
.OrderBy(x => x.CityId)
.ToList();
```

Comment: is there some reason to use SelectMany?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, this is the best way i know of to flatten a collection of collections into single collection. Do you know better alternatives?

Comment: `GroupBy` then `SelectMany` the grouped items, why not just `OrderBy` ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra, fair question. This answer is explaining what is wrong with OPs code and how to fix that. `OrderBy` might be a better alternative if described use case is the only one OP has, that is true

Comment: @YuliamChandra, added note suggesting `OrderBy` as an alternative

Comment: using SelectMany after GroupBy is just pointless.your alternative solution should be the actual solution, not alternative.

Comment: @Selman22, let me explain why I believe the answer is correctly aligned in its current form. If the purpose of the post was just to provide the best solution to the problem, then you are right. But my purpose was different. OP had an issue because they were missing some nuances on how LINQ methods work and what they return. I do believe that before suggesting a better solution one should explain what the problem with current approach is. I think we should always provide asker the full info, and let them decide themselves whether anything is pointless or not. Although we can advice for sure